# PCA vs t-SNE for data-visualisation: is there a way of doing loading plots with t-SNE?

Tags: r, data-visualization, pca

In the past i've used to using PCA and loading plots to visualise data using  stats::prcomp and ggbiplot. Like this:

[image: PCA example]

I've recently been introduced to [t-SNE analysis](https://www.r-bloggers.com/quick-and-easy-t-sne-analysis-in-r/) (late to the game here) that has been revolutionary in reduction analysis and exploring patterns in data.

While t-SNE is picking up clusters in my data that PCA can't clearly distinguish, the downside is that there's no loading plot to understand which characteristic influences each cluster in space.

Is there any way with t-SNE I can form some sort of loading plot? Or are there any complementary methods associated with t-SNE that can be used? I'd really like to keep the t-SNE plot over the PCA plot for visualizing a particular dataset, but without the loading plot it's not as informative.

Any ideas? Dummy data below:

```
library(FD)
library(ggbiplot)

# generate random data
a <- sample(x = 1:5, size = 100, replace = TRUE)
b <- sample(x = 1:5, size = 100, replace = TRUE)
c <- sample(x = 1:5, size = 100, replace = TRUE)
d <- sample(x = 1:5, size = 100, replace = TRUE)
e <- sample(x = 1:5, size = 100, replace = TRUE)
f <- sample(x = 1:5, size = 100, replace = TRUE)
g <- sample(x = 1:5, size = 100, replace = TRUE)

# make ordinal
a <- ordered(a, levels = 1:5)
b <- ordered(b, levels = 1:5)
c <- ordered(c, levels = 1:5)
d <- ordered(d, levels = 1:5)
e <- ordered(e, levels = 1:5)
f <- ordered(f, levels = 1:5)
g <- ordered(g, levels = 1:5)

#as dataframe
table <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c,d,e,f,g))


#PCA
pca <- prcomp(table,center = TRUE,scale. = TRUE)
ggbiplot(pca) 

#t-SNE
gower_dist <- daisy(table, metric = "gower")

tsne_obj <- Rtsne(gower_dist, is_distance = TRUE)

tsne_data <- tsne_obj$Y %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  setNames(c("X", "Y")) 

ggplot(aes(x = X, y = Y), data = tsne_data) +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: In short: No, that's not how t-SNE works. Individual low-dimensional axes in t-SNE have no (easily) interpretable meaning. Take a look at the following excellent posts on Cross Validated: [How to interpret t-SNE plot?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331745/how-to-interpret-t-sne-plot), [What is the meaning of the axes in t-SNE?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/348927/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-axes-in-t-sne).

Comment: [continued] I don't know your line of work but in my area t-SNE plots are both a curse and a blessing IMO. They can do an amazing job at preserving and visualising neighbourhood structures, producing beautiful plots of high-dimensional data; at the same time, the interpretability of the dimensions is lost, and it is important to keep in mind that t-SNE is first-and-foremost a pretty visualisation tool.

Comment: Ecology. So far t-SNE has been a revelation on the limited number of datasets I've tried it with. It preserves the clustering of groups as does PCA, but separates the structure of the data in a much clearer visualization than PCA. The only downside is the lack of a loading plot or way of interpreting drivers. Many thanks!